# getSubscription upon activation of sw

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake.

I want to register a service worker and the moment it's "activated" 
make an XHR request to my server in order to store the subscription data.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
    console.log('Activated', event);
    event.waitUntil(

        self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function (subscription) {

        console.log(subscription);//this is always null

        })
    )
})
```

So far I wasn't able to get the subscription inside the SW, I can from any other javascript on the site. What am I not udnerstanding?

Edit:

this is how I register to pushmanager

```
function reg(){

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

    navigator.serviceWorker.register(SW).then(function(reg) {

        reg.pushManager.subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true
        }).then(function(subscription) {
            send_subscription(subscription);
        });

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(':^(', error);
    });
  }
}

function send_subscription(subscription){ [...] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to get the subscription to a [`PushManager`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager):

> The PushManager.getSubscription() method of the PushManager interface retrieves an existing push subscription.

If this is intended, you first have to subscribe a `PushManager` using [`PushManager.subscribe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushManager/subscribe).

Comment: Right, I forgot to add that I'm indeed subscribing a `PushManager`, the problem I've found is that when I do so even if there's a promise to send `getSubscription()` to the server it doesn't work and the user must reload. Basically I'm trying to subscribe the user to push messages and send immediately the subscription data.

Comment: @sathia Please add the code that is doing the subscribing to your question.